# Accessing a one-dimensional array as a two-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, typeof

I have a one-dimensional array `int *data` and I know the number of `rows` and `cols` which are effectively stored within it. That is, I can access an element of the two-dimensional matrix `(i,j)` by using something like `data[i*cols+j]`.

Specifically, these are stored in a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int *data;
    int rows;
    int cols;
} matrix_t;
```

At some point in the past, I also wrote this voodoo code:

```
#define MATRIXP(m) __typeof__(__typeof__(__typeof__(*((m).data))[(m).cols]) *)
#define MATRIXD(m) ((MATRIXP(m)) ((m).data))
```

With these definitions, I am able to do:

```
MATRIXP(matrix) m = MATRIXD(matrix);
```

And then I can use the matrix `m` as a two-dimensional matrix pointer for accessing `data`.

```
m[3][2] = 5; /* assign the element in row 3 and column 2 */
```

This is very nice and means I don't need to remember to always have an expression like `data[i*cols+j]`. However, I wrote this code some time ago and I now cannot remember how it works.

1. Can someone please explain exactly how all those `__typeof__` operators are working, and how to go about reading similar expressions? What is the type of the variable `m`?

   I know it expands to something like:

   ```
   __typeof__(__typeof__(__typeof__(*((matrix).data))[(matrix).cols]) *) m = ((__typeof__(__typeof__(__typeof__(*((matrix).data))[(matrix).cols]) *)) ((matrix).data));
   ```
2. Is this method of accessing `data` safe? Is it the best way to do this?

Comment: +1, but You know that `c99` and later allows you to allocate continuous memory for multi dim array like that `int (*data)[cols] = malloc(sizeof(int[rows][cols]));`, i mean what you doing is nice, but it looks like there is a better way.

Comment: And in pre-C99 you can still do `int(*data)[cols] = malloc(sizeof(int)*rows*cols);`.

Comment: You can't put a field like `int (*data)[cols]` in the struct definition though. I am not really asking about how to allocate such a thing in the same scope it's used. I need to be able to pass it to other functions and access it easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1:

`MATRIXP(matrix) m` (`matrix` should be a variable of type `matrix_t`) will be expanded to

```
__typeof__(__typeof__(__typeof__(*((matrix).data))[(matrix).cols]) *) m
```

From in side to out side

1. `__typeof__(*((matrix).data))` is the type of `*((matrix).data)`, which is `int` according to the definition of `matrix_t`.
2. so `(__typeof__(*((matrix).data))[(matrix).cols])` equals `(int [cols])`
3. so `__typeof__(__typeof__(*((matrix).data))[(matrix).cols]) *)` equals `(int [cols] *)`
4. and that is the type given by `MATRIXP(matrix)`.

Therefore, `MATRIXP(matrix)` equals `(int [(matrix).cols] *)`. In other words,

```
MATRIXP(matrix) m
```

is effectively

```
int (*m)[matrix.cols]
```

As pointed out by @codebeard

Question 2:

It looks quite safe to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So `MATRIXP(matrix) m` is effectively `int (*m)[matrix.cols]`? Why would this cause a large allocation on the stack?

Comment: @codebeard Oh, it will not. My mistake, answer updated. Thank you for point that out.

Comment: I think part of the confusion for me is that while `__typeof(int *)__ x` is the same as `int *x`, `__typeof(int [5] *)__ x` is not `int [5] *x` but `int (*x)[5]`, and it's not 100% clear to my why this is.

Comment: @codebeard `__typeof` is the reason. `__typeof(int [5])` is a type of an array of five `int`s, however, `int [5]` is not a valid C type, so you cannot define a pointer to that type like this `int [5] *x`, and have to use `int (*x)[5]`. Also notices that `__typeof(int [5] *)` is invalid, you have to write it as `__typeof(__typeof(int [5]) *)`.